# Does this code have anything to do with pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

Could somebody help me with this piece of code.
I have no idea that what it does.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[5],i;
    int a = 1, n = 5;

    for (i=0; i<5;a+= arr[i++]);
    int d = a;
    printf("%d",d);

}
```

Comment: Since the content of `a[]` is indeterminate, you're not the only one in the dark on this: so is the code.

Comment: There are no pointers in the code.

Comment: There are no *explicit* pointers in the code, but in C technical terms there are pointers involved. (1) In the sub-expression `arr[i++]`, `arr` is converted to a pointer to the first element of array `arr`, and the sub-expression is equivalent to `*(arr + i++)`. (2) in the function call to `printf`, the function name is converted to a function pointer.

Comment: Run it and see? And if that's not enough, then single step through it with your favourite debugger and watch the values of all variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

technically this code has pointers. That is because arrays are pointers to the values that are stored in it(arr[0-5]). Every Element of the array points to a Adress anywhere in the memory.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[10];
    unsigned int x;

    for(x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        arr[x] = x;
        printf("%d ", *(arr+x));
    }
    return 0;

}
```

in this code you can see that you can use an pointer notation to navigate trough an array.

now to your second question. the code that you gave us here is first initializing a array with 5 elements, a int named 'i', a int named 'a' with the value 1, and a int named 'n' that has the value 5.

then you go into a for loop that repeats 5 times. in the for loop you give a the value of the array[i]. but because the array is not filled with numbers it comes a number that is anywhere in the memory.

next you give the variable 'd' the value of 'a'. and at least you print 'd'.

I think that you want it so that you go into a loop and it prints the elements of the array.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[5], i, a = 1, d;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        arr[i] = i;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a = arr[i];
        d = a;
        printf("%d ", d);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

i think that is what you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Of note, we've not put anything of interest into `arr`, however notice the semicolon on the end of this line:

```
for (i=0; i<5;a+= arr[i++]);
```

That's a succinct (confusing?) way of saying

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    a += arr[i];
}
```

So `a` is summing up whatever is in `arr`.